# Correct Sentence construction using Based on or Base on

Tags: sentence-construction

How to use Based on or Base in English Sentences?

Please help me with this example.

> This is your report "**base on/based on**" which you can proceed further.

According to me we should use "base on"

a) sentence is in Present tense.

b) "Based on" is not an Adjective.

c) Also, it is not used as passive voice.

Comment: Has the report already been produced?

Comment: Yes, Report has already been prepared and while giving it to the patient it was said.

Answer (score 5):

The correct sentence is

> This is your report **based on which** you can proceed further.

Here, "based on which" is a [relative pronoun preceded by a preposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Overview). With the remainder of the sentence, it forms a relative clause that describes *your report*.

This sentence can be modified to a simpler form which would be easier to analyze:

> You can proceed further based on your report.

Here, "based on your report" is an [adverbial clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause) constructed from a verb in the *passive voice*.  Another modification would give us

> You can base your further steps (how you proceed) on your report.

In this form it is an active voice sentence with the verb *base*.

Answer (score 0):

**This is your report "base on/based on" which you can proceed further.
According to me we should use "base on"
a) sentence is in Present tense..........b) "Based on" is not an Adjective.........c) Also, it is not used as passive voice**

In fact **Based** is an **Adjective**

> **This is your report "based on" which you can proceed further**.

Could be rewritten as

**This is your report from which you can develop further .............**

> **based**; adjective; [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/based)  if one thing is based on another, it is developed from it:
>
> be based on sth;   **All these new products were based on extensive market research.**

Answer (score -1):

I'm struggling to find the right words to explain this myself - but it's *not* a simple present tense [my memory is shaky but it may be a perfect tense?]
1. The report that we are talking about was produced at a past time [it must have been because it existed prior to you being able to show it, and it is a completed action]- and the contemplated action is future.

2. The contemplated action is going to occur in the future - so the subject to which you attach the adverbial clause [above] will dictate the tense to be used.
3. If you attach the adverbial clause to the REPORT - then the tense is past [perfect];
   but
   if you attach the adverbial clause to the contemplated action - then it will be future.